# inconsistent migration history when changing a django app's name

Tags: python, mysql, django, rename

I'm trying to rename one of the apps in my django website. There is another app which depends on it and its mysql tables. I went over all the files in both apps and changed the instances of the old name to the new one.

However, now I encounter this error message when trying to perform a migration:

```
File "/Users/Limor/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.10a1-py2.7.egg/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 287,
 in check_consistent_history
    migration[0], migration[1], parent[0], parent[1],
django.db.migrations.exceptions.InconsistentMigrationHistory: 
  Migration manual_tasks.0001_initial is applied before its dependency beta.0001_initial
```

I couldn't find a solution for this issue, and if I tried to comment out the particular function which raises the exception I run into related issues down the road. Am I doomed, or is there a way to fix it?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

the old name is version_1, the new is beta and the other app which relies on it is manual_tasks.

Here's the code's structure:

```
~/website/
|-- .ebextensions
|   `-- django.config
|-- project
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- local_settings.py
|   |-- settings.py
|   |-- urls.py
|   `-- wsgi.py
|-- db.sqlite3
|-- manage.py
|--beta
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- admin.py
|   |-- apps.py
|   |-- local_settings.py
|   |-- models.py
|   |-- tests.py
|   |-- urls.py
|   |-- views.py
|   |-- migrations
|       |-- __init__.py
|       |-- 0001__initial.py
|   |-- static
|       |-- assets
|       |-- images
|   |-- templates
|--manual_tasks
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- admin.py
|   |-- apps.py
|   |-- models.py
|   |-- tests.py
|   |-- urls.py
|   |-- views.py
|   |-- migrations
|       |-- __init__.py
|       |-- 0001__initial.py
|   |-- static
|       |-- assets
|       |-- images
|   |-- templates
`-- requirements.txt
```

Hope it makes more sense!

Comment: The problem is in your migration dependencies but it's hard to figure out from this info. Update your question with the old app name new app name and give an indication of what the project structure looks like now

Comment: yes, this makes things a lot clearer actually and there is hope since there is only one migration. Can probably be fixed by just editing the migration file. Could you post them if they are not very long. if they are long post just the dependency section and the fields that show foreign key relationships etc

Comment: Also, if the database doesn't have any data in it. Or the data is not important, you can just delete the database, delete the migration files and do it over again in less than a minute

Comment: Thank you! That was helpful and I was able to figure it out :)

Answer (score 7):

I think you already run migration named **version_1.0001_initial** before you renamed app to **beta**. All you need is to update database records in the table **django_migrations** and rename old app migrations to the new name using this SQL statement:

```
UPDATE django_migrations SET app = 'beta' WHERE app = 'version_1';
```

Comment: Man, how do you do this from the `./manage.py shell`? That is all i have access too :(

Comment: You can execute raw query directly for example: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly

Answer (score 1):

In my case, when I examined contents of the `django_migrations` table I could confirm the issue this `InconsistentMigrationHistory` exception was trying to raise. Thus one `0001_initial` record of an applied migration for **dependent** application an no record for the "independent" one.

I even came to the point where the name of an application I was trying to run `django-admin migrate` on **did not** matter. That made me believe there's some kind of *sanity check* happening on the table before any migration operation actually takes place.

*Deleting* the database record and calling the `migrate` subcommand for the dependency first would remove the block. Both, required `--fake-initial` flag since all the `Model`s were already present.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, and if it helps anyone in a similar situation:

I had this issue when copying over a *correct* database from the production server to a test instance, to emulate the data on it, so I knew the database was correct. I haven't dug down into why this set the migrations out of line, but (and I want to **emphasize** that I could easily experiment on this because I had data backed up) just emptying the `django_migrations` table and running `python manage.py migrations <app_name> --fake` solved it for me.